# Input ignored when using 2 time_fields in a row with rails update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, time

I have a daily medical report in my app where the user should be able to input the times that he takes his medication. I am creating a Daily report every night at midnight, and I want the user to be able to update each Daily. The problem is the Time attributes in my user model block the rest of the inputs. So if I try to input anything after the first time input in the form, it will update the first time and ignore all other inputs. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
<%= form_for(@daily) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :am_weight, "AM Weight" %>
        <%= f.text_field :am_weight %>

        <%= f.label :am_systolic, "AM Systolic" %>
        <%= f.text_field :am_systolic %>

        <%= f.label :am_diastolic, "AM Diastolic" %>
        <%= f.text_field :am_diastolic %>

        <%= f.label :am_pulse, "AM Pulse" %>
        <%= f.text_field :am_pulse %>

        <%= f.label :am_temp, "AM Temperature" %>
        <%= f.text_field :am_temp %>

        <%= f.label :am_meds, "AM Medication" %>
        <%= f.time_field :am_meds %>

        <%= f.label :miralax %>
        <%= f.time_field :miralax %>...
```

Anything after the first `time_field :am_meds` is ignored when I submit the form. The times are Time types in my Daily model.

Comment: I have an app with multiple time fields in a single model which works just fine.  I'm assuming this is rails 4 (since you're using time fields).  Does the log show it's passing the proper params in from the form?  If you check the record in the console is it appearing correctly?  Are any fields saved after the first time input? Are you making any changes in the model before you save the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that I was adding incrementally to my daily model, so I forgot to update the fields in my `params.require(:daily).permit()`.

Once I added the additional fields as parameters to the permit method, everything functioned as intended.